# Pass Current Location in Parameter Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am trying to pass the current user location in parameters to get the desired result. 
I am getting current location like this in my `viewDidLoad` Method:-

```
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
     locationManager.delegate = self
     locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
     locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
 }
```

After that I called `didUpdateLocations` method to get current location co-ordinates and created two variables in which I stored current location.

```
var latitude: String = ""
var longitude: String = ""

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
        self.latitude = "\(locValue.latitude)" ; self.longitude = "\(locValue.latitude)"
        print(self.latitude, self.longitude)
    }
```

But when I am trying to pass my current location in parameters I am getting no value.

```
let param: [String : Any] =
                                 ["lat": self.latitude,
                                  "lng": self.longitude,
                                  "truck_type": "2",
                                  "title": "home",
                                  "job_type": "Jobs"


                                 ]
    print(param)
    CommonUtils.showHudWithNoInteraction(show: true)

    Alamofire.request("api", method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        CommonUtils.showHudWithNoInteraction(show: false)
        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
                print(json)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.fleetOwnerTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

            break

        case .failure(_):
            print("Error")
            break

        }
    }
```

[image]
I don't know what am I doing wrong. How can I pass current location into parameters?

Comment: You are probably forming the params even before the lat long are reflected!

Comment: yes you are right what should I do to solve this

Comment: Where are you calling `Alamofire.request` from? The issue is that `locationManager(_:,didUpdateLocations:)` is an asynchronous function, so you most probably make the network request before the location would be updated.

Comment: ***You*** don't *call `didUpdateLocations`*, the **framework** calls the method asynchronously.

Comment: One way out would be to securing the location on app launch. So that by the time you reach your view controller you have the location already. This could be fickle as the user may deny the permission for location so you have to take that into account as well

Comment: @DávidPásztor.. How can I do this ?

Comment: @iOSer....but it is a long process I think

Comment: Ummm not necessarily!! Its pretty fast, if the the internet connection is decent. You might say 2-5 secs in total. Most of the apps do it on launch themselves.

Comment: @iOSer....Okay I will try that

Comment: @wings In which method you have this api call?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR...I just created a function for api call in which I have to pass the current location co-ordinates

Comment: @wings in api response do you store result in any array?

Comment: yes I created a struct to store the response

Comment: @wings do you want to call the api only once or everytime whenever the location is updated?

Comment: Sir every time when the location is updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192774/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-wings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the `didUpdateLocations` method to call the api and pass the current location

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.last {
        callAPI(location: location.coordinate)
    }
}
```

Your api calling method

```
func callAPI(location:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let param: [String : Any] =
        ["lat": "\(location.latitude)",
         "lng": "\(location.longitude)",
         "truck_type": "2",
         "title": "home",
         "job_type": "Jobs"
    ]
    //Alamofire.request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to pass them as parameter. Make your Location manager as a singleton.

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let shared = LocationManager()

    let locationManager : CLLocationManager

    override init() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    func start() {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else {
            return
        }

        print(mostRecentLocation)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Just call `LocationManager.shared.start()` to start the location updates and boom, you'll have the current location anytime in your app. You can of course create stop function to stop the location service once you are done.

Comment: How can I print values after calling `LocationManager.shared.start()`

Comment: Do that anywhere you want. Either in singleton's didUpdateLocations or in the other class's code line you want. Anywhere !!

Comment: I didn't  get this :( can you explain more

Comment: Check for the line - print(mostRecentLocation) - in the answer. This would print the latest location coordinates.